# plugin_host has exited unexpectedly in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I keep getting this while loading Sublime Text 3:

[image]

I didn't install any package lately.

Now I can not type use `shift` and `ctl` and more ...

### What have I tried :

- Even if after restart Sublime - still got the message.
- After reboot my computer also, still got the same issue.
- I also tried re-install the whole application again also.
- I also tried clean out all the junks in my computer using CCleaner that may have effect this.

Does anybody know how to fix this ?

Comment: Yes. I did that

Comment: You can try to check what executables are called by the plugins; one of those is probably the culprit, [I solved a similar issue](https://superuser.com/a/1406245/322610).