# SublimeText plugin_host crashes when I load a PHP file

Tags: php, plugins, sublime-text-3, packages

After I updated to the last version of SublimeText3 (build 3176) the *plugin_host* started to **crash every time that I select a tab with a PHP file**.

> plugin_host has exited unexpectedly, plugin functionality won't be available until Sublime Text has been restarted

I thought maybe some extension could be the culprit but can't debug which one.
I tried to put **all** the `installed_packages` to the `ignored_packages` in my *Package Control.sublime-settings*, but didn't help (actually I could still invoke plugin functions via the command palette;  but couldn't think of other ways to disable all extensions at once).

Answer (score 0):

## I managed to solve the problem in my case.

After update to the mot recent SublimeText version (3176), **plugin_host was crashing** each time that I switched to a tab containing a PHP file.*

I had **no detail of the error or stack-trace** so I could just guess.

In my case the issue was with the *PHP-CS (Code Sniffer)* extension of *SublimeLinter*, that was crashing. Removing it was preventing the crash.
Couldn't find any related issue on the github repository so **I assumed that the error was due to my local configuration** rather than a bug in the code.

I checked the *SublimeLinter* configuration and saw that there was an entry to `phpcs` setting a specific path for the `executable`, rather than relying on the *PATH* system environment variable in order to find it.

I tried to run the configured path (in my case was */usr/local/opt/php/bin/phpcs)* and verified that **the (configured) executable was the one crashing** (using `echo $?` revealed me the exit code 133).

So I tried to remove the *SublimeLinter* configuration relative to `phpcs` (making it rely on the system configuration for locating it), saved, restarted *Sublime* and voilà  it worked flawlessly without any more crash of *plugin_host*!
The pointed `phpcs` was the wrong one and I needed to use the one found under the *PATH* env.

I suppose that either the _plugin_host_ or *SublimeLinter* assume that the called executables will work correctly once found at their location, or that they don't handle correctly the exit-status from the processes and provoke a bigger crash in some scope/context where the error is not caught and the stack-trace is not generated (hence, no useful info in the log over the console).
I might be wrong on the diagnosis, but maybe this will help somebody else to track down the issue and find why these crashes happen instead of catching the exception

## In general I'd suggest to:

- look for the culprit among the **plugins that call external executables**
- **ensure that the paths are specified correctly**, pointing to the correct version of the executable
- **ensure that the executable actually works** outside of Sublime

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Check. Learned my lesson. I'll add a comment on the other question, pointing to this one.